# Open up a website on Android

Tags: android, web, android-intent

I want my Android app to open wikipedia.com as soon as the icon is pressed. I've set up everything correctly, it's just a programming problem. This is what I have so far in my src folder:

```
package com.wikipedia.lewicki;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WikipediaMobile extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I want to open the www.wikipedia.com home page.

Comment: Why not just store a shortcut to wikipedia.com on your home screen? You can do that from the browser bookmarks page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Intent to open wikipedia.

[Examples](http://snipt.net/Martin/android-intent-usage/)

Answer (score 1):

You can open URL into your browser using:

```
String url="www.wikipedia.com"  
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Are you want to show your url through device's default browser or in your webview?

Comment: for display url in browser just paste above three lines under your setContentView(R.layout.main); that's it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help piyush. But im getting all these errors on eclipse. Gonna get a developer. Good Luck :)